# Why is postgres taking computer user as login user?

Tags: postgresql, libpq, change-data-capture

I am trying to test wal2json on my system with Postgresql database. I have made changes in my postgresql.conf & pg_hba.conf file as shown in this link:

https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json

But when I am trying to create a test slot using postgres command, it is giving error:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin>pg_recvlogical -d mydatabase --slot test_slot --create-slot -P wal2json
Password:
pg_recvlogical: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "LENOVO"
```

What is interesting here is that none of my postgres users are of name LENOVO. LENOVO is my laptop login name. Any idea how to sort this out?

Comment: That's the default behaviour of all Postgres [command line tools](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/reference-client.html)  (to use the current operating system user as the database user to login). If you don't want that, simply provide a username `-U ....` or set the PGUSER [environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this is that you did not specify user name in database connection string parameters. Linux pg_recvlogical man page says:

```
-U user
--username=user
User name to connect as. Defaults to current operating system user name.
```

You need to add database user name to your connection string.